# Inequality: $\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H])^2] \le \mathbb E[(X-Z)^2]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$. Suppose $X$ is square-integrable and $\mathcal H$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$. Then $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]$ is square-integrable and for all square-integrable and $\mathcal H$-measurable $Z$ it holds that

$$\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H])^2] \le \mathbb E[(X-Z)^2]$$

---

To show that $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]$ is square-integrable I first note that
$|\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]|^2\le \mathbb E[|X|^2\mid \mathcal H]$ by the conditional Jensen's inequality. Now, taking expecations gives
$$\mathbb E[|\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal H]|^2]\le \mathbb E[\mathbb E[|X|^2\mid \mathcal H]] = \mathbb E[|X|^2] <\infty$$
So $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]$ is indeed square-integrable.

But how to do the second part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: For every $Z$ in $L^2(\mathcal H)$, $$X-Z=X-\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]+\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]-Z,$$ where $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]-Z$ is in $L^2(\mathcal H)$, and $X-\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]$ is orthogonal to $L^2(\mathcal H)$. Thus, good ol'Pythagoras saves the day.

Comment: What does it mean for $X-\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]$ to be orthogonal to $L^2(\mathcal H)$ ?

Comment: The canonical scalar product on $L^2$ is defined by $\langle U,V\rangle=E(UV)$. The random variable is orthogonal to the subspace for this scalar product. Studying conditional expectations for square integrable random variables without ever mentioning orthogonality?

Comment: Thank you, now I see it: For any $Z\in L^2(\mathcal H)$ we have $\langle X-\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H],Z\rangle=0 \iff \mathbb E[XZ]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]Z]$ and $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]Z]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[XZ\mid \mathcal H]]=\mathbb E[XZ]$.